# Paracol footnote customization

Tags: footnotes, paracol

I'm doing a multilingual project in two columns and I've tried a bunch of column packages, and from what I've seen `paracol` does the most perfect and satisfying job for all intents and purposes. Though I have some customization issues – because (I think) `paracol` overrides certain functions that I cannot alter anymore in the traditional sense.

This code with two footnotes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\footnotelayout{p} % <----

\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{leftcolumn}
Test.\footnote{Ahoy.} \lipsum[1]
\end{leftcolumn}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Another test.\footnote{Aloha.} \lipsum[1]
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

produces the footnotes **a.** stacked each in a new line, and **b.** with a horizontal line. The only way I found to customize the footnotes within `paracol` was the `\footnotelayout{}`-function, which also just has limited capabilites of real customization.

How can I have **a.** the footnotes altogether in the same line and **b.** without the line, so that it looks somewhat like this:

[image]